# Need help on React Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, jsx

I am new to React Js and my code is not working. Please have a look below:

This is my script file **Main.jsx**. This file is compiled by react and output is put in main.js file under 'dist' folder.

```
var react = require("react"),
reactDom = require("react-dom");
var myComponent = react.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <div><h4>I am rendered by react.</h4></div>;
    }
});

reactDom.render(<myComponent />, document.getElementById("basicDiv"));
```

It is **Index.html**

```
<html>    
<head>
    <base href="./" />
    <title>App title</title>    
    <script src="node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="basicDiv"></div>

    <!-- React compiled code is in dist folder and is accessible -->
    <script src="dist/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run the index.html file in browser the **Output is** blank screen. Please see the below screenshot of chrome dev tools inspector window:

[image: Output in browser]

The content of 'myComponent' is not rendered in browser. I have seen many tutorials with the same code but it is not working... don't know why.

Please help on this and if possible, provide me some sample code / tutorials for latest releases also. Thanks in advance

**Update**

Please note that I have included React library reference in my HTML file which makes me to freely use "React" or "react" as a variable name while importing React in my script files. Taking "React" (with capital R) as variable name is not mandatory here in this case.

**Final Update**

So the solution (as answered by Damien Leroux) is to make the react component variable-name starting with a capital letter. 'var myComponent' must be 'var MyComponent' or 'var Mycomponent'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A react class must always begin with an Upper case letter:

```
var MyComponent = react.createClass({
```

read [user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: You are the genius on this page man .... thanks. I changed `var myComponent` to `var MyComponent`. It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

Not only your React Component must begin with a Upper case letter, See this:

[React - Adding component after AJAX to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view/41216726#41216726)

but you must also Import react like

```
var React = require("react"),
ReactDom = require("react-dom");
```

i.e UpperCase Letters since internally JSX is transpiled to  `React.createElement()` in which case it will say that react is not defined.

You code must look like

```
var React = require("react"),
ReactDom = require("react-dom");
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <div><h4>I am rendered by react.</h4></div>;
    }
});

ReactDom.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("basicDiv"));
```

Comment: >>since react internally uses React.createElement() in which case it will say that react is not defined. ..... To counter this error I have included React's reference in my html. I do not get that error with non-capital variable for importing react. Though this doesn't answer the problem I explained in screenshot above...

Comment: I would suggest you to use Webpack to bundle your code. Follow the youtube react tutorial by LeanCodeAcademy

Comment: yes @Shubham Khatri, I would use something like webpack, but as I am starting on react, I want to manually go through this whole lib-loading and all stuff.

Comment: @Shivam Its better to get directly started with webpack. I read somewhere that browser support for babel has been retracted, that may also be the reason you are facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react'
import './Aboutus.css'
import Header from '../Home/Header/Header.jsx'
import Footer from '../Home/Footer/Footer.jsx'

var stylesheader = {
  paddingTop: 50, 
  textAlign:'center', 
  color: '#204871'
};

var stylehead = {
  paddingLeft: 200,
  paddingRight:200, 
  paddingTop:20, 
  color: '#204871'
};

var styles = {
  paddingTop: 120, paddingLeft:20,
  color: '#128bea', 
  fontSize: 26
};

var style1 = {
  paddingTop:100,
  color: '#204871' 
};

class Aboutus extends React.Component {

    render() {

  var title = "we are a team";

  var leadership = [
  {
    "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "phone":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  },
  {
     "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "phone":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  }
  ];

  var business = [
  {
     "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  },
  {
       "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  },
  ];

  var algorithm = [
  {
       "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  },
  {
       "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  },
  {
      "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  },
  {
       "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  }
  ];

   var developer = [
  {
      "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  },
  {
       "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  },
  {
      "name":"abc",
    "department":"abc",
    "email":"abc"
  }
  ];

     var row1=leadership.map(row => {
                              return <div className="column">
                                       <div className="card"> 
                                          <div className="container">
                                              <h2>{row.name}</h2>
                                              <p>{row.department}</p>
                                              <p>{row.phone}</p>
                                              <p>{row.email}</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div> 
                              });

      var row2=business.map(row => {
                              return <div className="column">
                                       <div className="card"> 
                                          <div className="container">
                                              <h2>{row.name}</h2>
                                              <p>{row.department}</p>
                                              <p>{row.email}</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div> 
                              });

       var row3=algorithm.map(row => {
                              return <div className="column">
                                       <div className="card"> 
                                          <div className="container">
                                              <h2>{row.name}</h2>
                                              <p>{row.department}</p>
                                              <p>{row.email}</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div> 
                              });

       var row4=developer.map(row => {
                              return <div className="column">
                                       <div className="card"> 
                                          <div className="container">
                                              <h2>{row.name}</h2>
                                              <p>{row.department}</p>
                                              <p>{row.email}</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div> 
                              });

      return (

         <div className="home-component">

                <div className="home-header">
                <Header/>
                </div>

                <div className="home-content" >
                            <h1 style={stylesheader}> Meet the team </h1>
                            <h2 style={stylehead}>{title}</h2>

                            <h2 style={styles}> Leadership </h2>
                            <div className="row" style={style1}>
                              {row1}
                            </div>

                            <h2 style={styles}> Business Development </h2>
                            <div className="row" style={style1}>                    
                             {row2}                           
                            </div>

                            <h2 style={styles}> Algorithm Development </h2>
                            <div className="row" style={style1} >                    
                             {row3}                         
                            </div>

                            <h2 style={styles}>Software Development </h2>
                             <div className="row" style={style1} >                    
                              {row4}
                             </div>  
                </div>

                <Footer/>

         </div>
    );

    }
}

export default Aboutus;
```