# React - User-Defined JSX Components Not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've been trying to make an AJAX call and then add it to my view after it has been retrieved.

Nothing really happens with the current code.

```
const View = () => (
    <div>
     <h1>Reports</h1>
   <statisticsPage />
    </div>
);
export default View;


var statisticsPage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
     return {info: "loading ... "};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
     this.requestStatistics(1);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>info: {this.state.info}</div>
    );
  },
  requestStatistics:function(){
      axios.get('api/2/statistics')
      .then(res => {
        values = res['data']
        this.setState({info:1})
        console.log('works!!')
      });

    }

  })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You component name must begin with an Uppercase character since those beginning with lowercase are searched as default DOM elements like `div, p, span etc`. Which is not the case for your `statisticsPage` component. Make it uppercase and it works fine.

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized):

> When an element type starts with a `lowercase` letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like  or  and results in a string `'div'`
>   or 'span' passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your `JavaScript` file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
>   component that starts with a `lowercase` letter, assign it to a
>   capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

```js
const View = () => (
    <div>
     <h1>Reports</h1>
   <StatisticsPage />
    </div>
);



var StatisticsPage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
     return {info: "loading ... "};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
     this.requestStatistics();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>info: {this.state.info}</div>
    );
  },
  requestStatistics:function(){
        console.log('here');
        this.setState({info:1})
        console.log('works!!')
      

    }

  })

ReactDOM.render(<View/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```