# Unable to load second component in first component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, components

Why is my second component not loading in the first component? Here is the code:

```
var ComponentOne = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
          <h1>ComponentOne</h1>
          <componentTwo />
        </div>
      )
    },
  });

  var componentTwo = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
          <h2> componentTwo </h2>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
```

Here I have added second component in the first component by `<componentTwo />` but still not displaying.

Here is [a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/b0Ia2YJeWm9KJdiXyZGT?p=preview).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Adding component after AJAX to view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view)

Answer (score 2):

Just start your component2 with capital letter and it would work

something like

```
var ComponentOne = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
          <h1>ComponentOne</h1>
          <ComponentTwo />
        </div>
      )
    },
  });

  var ComponentTwo = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
          <h2> componentTwo </h2>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
```

Why capitals? explanation can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505/2551236

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Can I know why capitals for components name.

Comment: @RamanaUday custom components must start with capital letters as built in components (`div`, `h1`, `p`, etc.) use lowercase.  See [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) for more details.

Comment: @RamanaUday if this answer helps you, please accept it so that others facing same issue can get the problem solved