# React babel loader - you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

[image]The time to compile with webpack this error is triggered : 
you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I use this libraries:

[image]

This is my project files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base app --inline --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./app/dist/index.js",
  module:{
      loaders:[
          {
              test:/\.(js | jsx)?$/,
              exclude:/(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              loader:'babel-loader',
              query:{
                  presets:['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                  plugins:['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
              }
          }
      ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/app/js",
    filename: "index.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class layout extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
        );
    }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<layout/>, app);
```

index.html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <tittle>React</tittle>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app"></div>
            <script src="index.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test expression is wrong,it has extra spaces in `/\.(js | jsx)?$/`

Use

```
test: /\.jsx?$/,
```

or

```
test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
```

Apart from this you will need to change the name of your React Component to begin with Uppercase character. See this answer [React - Adding component after AJAX to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view/41216726#41216726)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Layout extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
        );
    }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, app);
```

Comment: The two options failed to compile.

Comment: There is no difference apart from the regex, how can they fail to compile

Comment: Sorry i dont writed my answer correctly, i put the two options but yet failed to compile, maybe is other thing.

Comment: And where does it give a compilation erroe

Comment: I put the img of the output cmd in the top