# webpack4: React babel - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm new to webpack 4/react/babel, and i am getting the error below:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| ReactDOM.render(
>     <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
|     document.getElementById("example")
| );
```

i tried this soluction:[link from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311366/react-babel-loader-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type)  but also didn't work.

So i am stuck, the main difference is that i am using webpack 4 (remarks that i didn't made it work with webpack 3)

My enviroment is:

- windows:10
- nodejs:6.9.5

Below are the files with the relative path of them

./package.json

```
{
  "name": "using-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "webpack": "^4.16.1"
  }
}
```

./.babelrc

```
{
    "presets":[
        "es2015", "react"
    ]
}
```

./webpack.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
        mode:"development",
    entry: {
        javascript: "./src/index.js",
        html: "./src/index.html",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test:"/\.js$/",
                exclude:"/node_modules/",
                loader:"babel-loader",
            },
        ]
    },////

    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

./index.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Hello } from "./components/hello";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
    document.getElementById("example")
);
```

./components/hello.js

```
import * as React from "react";


// 'HelloProps' describes the shape of props.
// State is never set so we use the '{}' type.
export class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello from {this.props.compiler} and {this.props.framework}!</h1>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module section has plain strings in it when it should have regex instead.

Remove the quotes around your regex! :)

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { 
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader:"babel-loader",
        },
    ]
},
```

Comment: I am having similar issue despite using regex `/\.jsx?$/`

Comment: @Hussain - You may want to create your own question for that as it could be a number of configuration issues causing your problem.