# Child component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I can't for the life of me work out why my component isn't rendering in the page at all, well its rendering as `<signinform></signinform>`. I am using `react-form` but I don't think this has anything to do with it not rendering.

**signin.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import {BlockForLoggedInUsers} from '../shared/auth/userRedirects'
import Logo from '../shared/logo';
import userStyles from '../shared/userPages/userPages.css';
import showResults from './showResults';
import signInForm from './signInForm';

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className={userStyles.home}>
        <BlockForLoggedInUsers />
        <Logo />
        <signInForm onSubmit={showResults}/>
        <div className={userStyles.extraDetails}>
          <NavLink to="/signup">Don't have an account yet?</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/skip" className={userStyles.extraDetailsRight}>Skip</NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { user: state.user };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn);
```

**signInForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const signInForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <form role="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field name="email" component="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter email address"/>
        <button type="submit"  disabled={pristine || submitting}>Sign In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signInForm',
})(signInForm);
```

**HTML Output**
[image]

Comment: I think the problem here can be solved with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view/41216726#41216726

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React components names should be capitalized - so just change component name from `signInForm` to `SignInForm`. Please check react [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) for more details.

Comment: Bingo! Easy correct answer there :D

Comment: @JamieHutber, Its a duplicate of the above answer then :)