# Convert String in React Components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a string which is actually a nested react components name with its props. Want to render that string inside another react component .
For example

```
var String = "<parentComponent title='Parent'><childComponent age='23'></childComponent></parentComponent>"
```

React Code: -

```
class MainComponnet extends Component{
 render(){
  let stringComponents = "<parentComponent title='Parent'><childComponent age='23'></childComponent></parentComponent>";
  return(
     {stringComponents}
  )
 }
}
```

Parent Component JSX : -

```
class ParentComponent extends Component{
 render(){
  return(
     <div> {this.props.title}</div>
  )
 }
}
```

Child Component JSX : -

```
class ChildComponent extends Component{
 render(){
  return(
     <div> {this.props.age}</div>
  )
 }
}
```

Please help..

Comment: One question why is it inside a string?

Comment: Actually service would be returning the component string and accordingly I have to render that components.

Comment: I think doing this is somewhat not possible.Probably you need a react-jsx-parser here to convert you string to a normal component type thing and then render it

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Am hunting for such parser online, hard luck . Is there any way that you can help me

Comment: Not sure, but can you try this https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser

Comment: Thanks Vivek.. react-jsx-parser solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string has JSX content, you can directly render JSX contents, also the component names must begin with Uppercase charater.

See this answer: [React - Adding component after AJAX to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view/41216726#41216726)

```
class MainComponnet extends Component{
 render(){
  let stringComponents = <ParentComponent title='Parent'><ChildComponent age='23'></ChildComponent></ParentComponent>;
  return(
     </div>{stringComponents}</div>
  )
 }
}
```

In case you cannot use a direct JSX element, you can transform your string to JSX using babel. However its not a good idea. you should rather modify your logic.

You can do it as follows

```
import babel from 'babel-core';
var Component = eval(babel.transform('<ParentComponent title='Parent'><ChildComponent age='23'></ChildComponent></ParentComponent>).code);
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply @Shubham but if you will notice my string is surronded by double quotes and yours not. Its data type is string hence while render its not processing react component.

Comment: Exactly my point, you dont need to surround your string within double quotes, directly assign the JSX content to the variable

Comment: I don't have any other options, this is what am getting in json from backend. If I can remove that quotes on UI or any other way to load component from String would be helpful.

Comment: Added that part in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks alot for every one for helping me. 
Library 'react-jsx-parser' solved my problem .