# What I'm getting blank page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and when I say new I mean just started. I can't figure out why I'm not getting any header or paragraph to show.

This is what's in my script tag which has type text/babel

```
var myElements = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return  <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph </p>
  }
});

React.render(<myElements/>, document.body);
```

I also have babel cdn in my header

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Is your babel transpiler hooked up right? Are you importing React?

Comment: Have you used your browser's developer tools to see if you get any error?

Comment: Besides that there many things unclear with your setup, the 1. problem which is obvious to me, is that you are returning multiple elements, wrap your elements in a `div` -> return `<div><h1>Hello</h1><p>Text</p></div>`

Comment: The problem was solved by wrapping elements inside a div.

Comment: You need to have a single HTML tag wrap all children so wrap the `h1` and `p` tag in a `div`. Also, the `render` function is provided by `react-dom` not `react` so make sure you have that too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Adding component after AJAX to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component should start with upper case. [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html](http://react-docs)

```js
var MyElements = React.createClass({
render: function(){
return  <h1>Hello </h1>
  }
});

React.render(<MyElements/>, document.body);
```

Comment: someone down voted my answer. Can you please comment why?

Comment: not having my component capitalized and not wrapping my element inside a div was the reason why I was getting a blank page so your answer was definitely right. I would upvote if I could.