# Rendering noMatch in React Router v4 doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

This is my code:

```
class noMatch extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return 'Not Found'
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/(index.html)?' component={App}/>
        <Route component={noMatch}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
  mountNode
);
```

The app runs in localhost:3000/ and localhost:3000/index.html as expected. but when there's no match, my no Match doesnt render? I am following the noMatch tutorial from the docs [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md). Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Adding component after AJAX to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view)

Comment: check the Duplicate question, the answer on that will help you understand your mistake. Let me know if you still cannot solve the problem

Comment: I capitalized my NoMatch component but it still don't work.

Comment: Any error in console

Comment: just the 404 not found. but I am expecting the NoMatch component to render

Comment: Did you change `<Route component={NoMatch}/>`. If yes then try `<Route path='*' component={NoMatch}/>`

Comment: yes I did. but still Cannot GET error :(

Comment: are you serving your index.html through nodeJS. If yes then how

Comment: I did  new WebpackDevServer(compiler, { contentBase: '/public/index.html', ... } so I can render on localhost:3000/

Answer (score 0):

Your router code looks find. If you are just returning string in your noMatch component, you should return valid React element such as this:

```
class noMatch extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Not Found</div>
        );
    }
}
```