# React/Node - Include js component in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import

I have a component in a .js file which I have exported as default. I am trying to include this component in another .js file. I have also imported this component in the other file. I have tried using `<componentName />` but this does not seem to work, it compiles and shows no error but nothing shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: This answer should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-adding-component-after-ajax-to-view/41216726#41216726

Comment: First of all as you are saying you are using it like `<componentName />`, this won't work, you should try renaming it with all caps ie `<ComponentName />`. Please share the code so that we can help you. This is just an assumption.

Comment: You guys should have posted that as an answer... worked a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as you are saying you are using it like `<componentName />`, this won't work, you should try renaming it with all caps ie. `<ComponentName />`. This is just an assumption. If the issue persists, please share the code, so that we can help you in a better way.
Discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4695).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the component name that I was attempting to add is required to start with a capital letter as components beginning with lowercase letters are searched as default DOM elements