# How to render when the function is a character string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble with React's Render processing.
There is a function called func1 and func2, which is called when rendering (eg: `return (<func1 />)`).

For example, I want to render as the actual function name from the character string at funcName in the JSON value like the following, how can I do it?

```
{funcName: "func1"}
```

If it is the above value,

I want to render as "`return (<func1 />)`"

Although I tried to solve this problem,  even if it is used by eval or rendering it in a variable it will result in an error.

Why do you want to do this processing now is rendering with the following processing, because it is troublesome because you need to add an if statement every time you add a new function.

```
if (funcName.func1! = null) {
  return `<func1 />`
} else if (funcName.func2! = null) {
  return `<func2 />`
}
```

An if statement is also added each time a function is added
that's all.

Please answer if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, React components name must begin with uppercase character, check this question for more details

[React - User-Defined JSX Components Not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-user-defined-jsx-components-not-rendering/41216726#41216726)

**Secondly** instead of storing

```
{funcName: "Func1"}
```

you would store

```
{funcName: Func1}
```

and then render like

```
render() {
    const Func1  = obj.funcName;
    return <Func1/>
}
```

or if you can't replace the string with component in your data, you would do

```
render() {
    const Func1  = eval(obj.funcName);
    return <Func1/>
}
```

Comment: Sorry , It is not possible to include an object type in Json data. I want to convert from string to function and rendering. However, it was not possible to render using the eval Method.

Comment: Did you try `const Func1  = eval(obj.funcName);
    return <Func1/>`

Comment: I changed it by converting the string with eval and declaring it in uppercase letters. I discovered that it was an error because the variable was lowercase. Thank you for pointing that out.
 
const Func = eval (obj.funcName)
return (<Func />)

Comment: Glad to have helped, consider accepting the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it as element `<func2 />` call the function `func2()`
But you func2 must return a valid react element.