# How to call reactjs routing in another file

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I would like to ask a general question.
I have a `menuContent.js` which is something like that.

```
class MenuContent extends Component {  


     constructor(props) {
     super(props)
      this.items = [];


    //   for (let i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    //  //   this.items.push(i)
    //   }
     }


  render() {

    return (

            <div className="menu">

               <a
                href="/animation/animation"
                onClick={this.props.closeCallback}
            >

                <img src={animation} alt="good as"/>
                animation
            </a>
            <br />
            <br />

     )
  }
}
```

and also a file which is called routing.js, which is something like that

```
class routing extends Component {  


     constructor(props) {
     super(props)
      this.items = [];


    //   for (let i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    //  //   this.items.push(i)
    //   }
     }


  render() {

    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <div className="menu">

                <ul className="header">
                                <li><NavLink to="/animation/animation">Animation</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/bars/bars">Bars</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
                <div className="content">
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/animation/animation" component={Animation}/>
                    <Route path="/bars/bars" component={Bars}/>
                </div>
```

but i don't know how to call the routing.js into the menucontent file except for  `<routing />`  into a the menucontent class

Comment: What exactly is the issue in using `<routing />` apart from the fact that your component name must start with uppercase character. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216654/react-user-defined-jsx-components-not-rendering/41216726#41216726

Comment: I'm getting the following error::::


Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Route`.

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the Home, Animation and Bars component correctly and also exported them correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have fully understood your question, but here is how to reuse components in React.

Simply code your Component as you wish and export it

```
import React from 'react';

class Routing extends React.Component {
    // code of component
}

export default Routing;
```

Now, your component Routing is available for any other script.

To reuse it, simply import it and use it like if it was in the same file.

```
import React from 'react';
import Routing from './Routing.js';

function() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Routing />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I want to put some working links inside the menuContent file, but if i am adding   <Routing /> , i'm just adding  the new page into MenuContent area and it doesn't load the page into the App area

Comment: I fixed that by adding # in the path.. so it's like that now 

<a
                    href="#/animation/animation"
                 
                >
                <img src={animation} alt="good as"/>