# what different import 'react' and 'react-native' in same file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In some example, I saw :

```html
import React, {
 Component
} from 'react';

import {
 StyleSheet, Text,...
} from 'react-native';
```

---

I know the 'react-native' purpose, but I don't understand why they import 'React' in some example? it makes me confused...

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help on React Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401224/need-help-on-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import React from 'react'` is required for JSX to work.

Under the hood, JSX is being transpiled to `React.createElement(...)` invocations.  So, even though you don't have to type `React.createElement()`, JSX still requires `React` to be active in the module namespace so that it can do it for you.

[Example of what React looks like without the transpilation step.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: So that's how it is, I appreciate your kind assistance :)

Comment: You're welcome.  If you find the answer useful, please mark it as answered.  It's a nice way to say thank you.