# why render function not call in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to show my list in react using component .But it not display .I do like this

https://codesandbox.io/s/lYMwLM591

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class ImageSlider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.props.data.hl}</div>);
  }
}

export default ImageSlider;
```

a**nother components**

```
 renderStories() {
    if (this.props.stories && this.props.stories.items > 0) {
      return this.props.stories.items.map(story => {
        return <ImageSlider data={story}/>;
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        lll
        {this.renderStories()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
renderStories() {
  if (this.props.stories && this.props.stories.items > 0) {
    return this.props.stories.items.map(story => {
      return <ImageSlider data={story}/>;
    });
  }
}
```

to:

```
renderStories() {
  if (this.props.stories && this.props.stories.items && this.props.stories.items.length > 0) {
    return this.props.stories.items.map(story => {
      return <ImageSlider data={story}/>;
    });
  }
}
```

should make it works.

Also in `/components/image.slider.js`, you should import React, otherwise, an error like `React is not defined` will display.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty simple, you need to check the `length of items array`

```
if (this.props.stories && this.props.stories.items.length > 0) {
  return this.props.stories.items.map(story => {
    return <ImageSlider data={story}/>;
  });
}
```

And import React in `ImageSlider` component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

See this answer: [Need help on React Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401224/need-help-on-react-js/40402119#40402119)

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/zK564QEyy)**

Answer (score 0):

You also have to do this

`import React, { Component } from 'react;`